# Hide jButton in Netbeans

Tags: hide, jbutton, visible

Is there a way to hide a jButton in Netbeans? (similar to button.visible = false in VS)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for, `button.setVisible(false);`

Answer (score 4):

myButton.setVisible(false);